# How should I structure an array to aid referencing data within?

Tags: php

Imagine I have an array of data. Each item in it is another array containing 'id', 'link' and 'display':

```
$travel = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'link' => 'bus',
        'display' => 'bus'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'link' => 'bike',
        'display' => 'bicycle'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'link' => 'cart',
        'display' => 'horse and cart'
    )
);
```

To display 'display' by a known id (`$id`) I would need to do something like:

```
foreach($travel as $t) {
    if($t['id'] == $id) {
        echo $t['display'];
        break;  // uuurgh, nasty...
    }
}
```

Equally, to display 'display' by a known link (`$link`) I would need to do the same:

```
foreach($travel as $t) {
    if($t['link'] == $link) {
        echo $t['display'];
        break;
    }
}
```

To be more efficient I could create two similar arrays:

```
$travelID = array(
    1 => array(
        'link' => 'bus',
        'display' => 'bus'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'link' => 'bike',
        'display' => 'bicycle'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'link' => 'cart',
        'display' => 'horse and cart'
    )
);

$travelLink = array(
    'bus' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'display' => 'bus'
    ),
    'bike' => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'display' => 'bicycle'
    ),
    'cart' => array(
        'id' => 3,
        'display' => 'horse and cart'
    )
);
```

and then perform the following:

```
echo $travelID[$id]['display'];
echo $travelLink[$link]['display'];
```

But is there a way of keeping all the data together whilst still being able to reference it simply/quickly?

Comment: Why is that so bad? It is just what I am doing in most cases where I use multidimentional arrays

Comment: @OptimusCrime Which option? The two seperate arrays option seems like data duplication and I assume the looping through one array option would be time consuming

Comment: The first one. Unless you have a REALLY big array, this is not a problem at all. Done in a tiny, tiny portion of time anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $keys = array('id', 'link');
    $multiple_key_array = new MultipleKeyArray($keys);

    $data_1 = array('id' => 1, 'link' => 'bus', 'display' => 'bus');
    $multiple_key_array->addData($data_1);

    $data_2 = array('id' => 2, 'link' => 'bike', 'display' => 'bicycle');
    $multiple_key_array->addData($data_2);

    $data_3 = array('id' => 3, 'link' => 'cart', 'display' => 'horse and cart');
    $multiple_key_array->addData($data_3);

    var_dump($multiple_key_array->getData('id', 1));

class MultipleKeyArray{

    private $data_array     = array();
    private $key_array      = array();
    private $map_array      = array();

    public function __construct($key_array){

        $this->key_array = $key_array;

    }

    public function addData($data_array){

        $index = count($this->data_array);
        $this->data_array[] = $data_array;


        foreach($this->key_array as $key){

            if(array_key_exists($key, $data_array)){

                $this->map_array[$key][$data_array[$key]] = $index;

            }

        }

    }

    public function getData($key, $value){

        $index = $this->map_array[$key][$value];
        return $this->data_array[$index];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, you can create just a hepler, such as `array_find_by(&$array);` Where to put all necessary code in order to NOT duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create "lookup" hashmaps, almost like an index in a database, simple example:

```
<?php
$travel = getData();
$idx_id = createIndex($travel, 'id');

$idx_id[2]['foo'] = 'bar';
var_dump($travel);

function createIndex(&$arr, $elementName) {
    $rv = array();
    foreach( $arr as &$entry ) {
        if ( isset($entry[$elementName]) ) {
            $rv[ $entry[$elementName] ] = &$entry;
        }
    }
    return $rv;
}

function getData() {
    return array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'link' => 'bus',
            'display' => 'bus'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'link' => 'bike',
            'display' => 'bicycle'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'link' => 'cart',
            'display' => 'horse and cart'
        )
    );
}
```

prints

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["link"]=>
    string(3) "bus"
    ["display"]=>
    string(3) "bus"
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["link"]=>
    string(4) "bike"
    ["display"]=>
    string(7) "bicycle"
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
  [2]=>
  &array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["link"]=>
    string(4) "cart"
    ["display"]=>
    string(14) "horse and cart"
  }
}
```

see http://docs.php.net/references